# Apache Spark Not able to view output

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have just started learning Apache Spark. I am trying to print the output of links but it doesn't display it for some reason. I have also tried links.collect() , display(links) but none of them work. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Complete Stack trace for second image:

```
 Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-34-01e857cfa45e> in <module>()
  ----> 1 for link in links.collect():
        2         print("%s" %(link))

  /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py in collect(self)
      769         """
      770         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
  --> 771             port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
      772         return list(_load_from_socket(port, self._jrdd_deserializer))
      773 

  /databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
      811         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
      812         return_value = get_return_value(
  --> 813             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
      814 
      815         for temp_arg in temp_args:

  /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
       43     def deco(*a, **kw):
       44         try:
  ---> 45             return f(*a, **kw)
       46         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
       47             s = e.java_exception.toString()

  /databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
      306                 raise Py4JJavaError(
      307                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
  --> 308                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
      309             else:
      310                 raise Py4JError(

  Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
  : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 4 in stage 24.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 4.0 in stage 24.0 (TID 76, localhost): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
      process()
    File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
      serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
    File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2346, in pipeline_func
      return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
    File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2346, in pipeline_func
      return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
    File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 317, in func
      return f(iterator)
    File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1776, in combineLocally
      merger.mergeValues(iterator)
    File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 236, in mergeValues
      for k, v in iterator:
    File "<ipython-input-31-4b09041aa30b>", line 1, in <lambda>
    File "<ipython-input-28-f43debc22073>", line 3, in parseNeighbors
    File "/databricks/python/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 171, in split
      return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)
  TypeError: expected string or buffer

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PairwiseRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:342)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: @shekhar I tried that, you can see in the second image. It still doesn't work.

Comment: post the complete traceback. the thing is nothing is actually computed before you collect, so the error is most likely from above, but appears only in the end.

Comment: @marmouset I have edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mapping function is wrong the error is similar to

```
re.split(r'\s+',[('a b')])
```

Try to replace it by

```
parts=re.split(r'\s+',urls[0])
```

which will send

```
re.split(r'\s+',('a b'))
```

The entire row is sent to your map function, so you need to access cells by calling them, eg .map(lambda row: (row[0], row[1])

Comment: I changed that, I still get an error when I try to print it.

Comment: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: Try again, it works sqlContext.createDataFrame([('a b',),('a c',)],['website links']).map(lambda urls: [re.split(r'\s+',urls[0])[0],re.split(r'\s+',urls[0])[1]]).collect()